# Differentiate and replace single for multiple string list elements

Tags: python, list

Require each list element to be a single string. Second list element contains multiple strings:

```
suburbs = ['Wamuomata'],['Wan', 'omata'],['Eastboume']
```

Required to be:

```
suburbs = ['Wamuomata'],['Wan omata'],['Eastboume']
```

Code:

```
suburbs = ['Wamuomata'],['Wan', 'omata'],['Eastboume']

for x in range(len(suburbs)):
        elementNumber = len(suburbs[x])
        if elementNumber > 1:
            for y in range(elementNumber):
                print(suburbs[x][y])
                
                    

print(suburbs)
```

Output:

```
Wan
omata
(['Wamuomata'], ['Wan', 'omata'], ['Eastboume'])
```

The output from `print(suburbs[x][y])` references the list strings of element two correctly. However don't know how to replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.join` on each list to turn it into a single string:

```
>>> suburbs = ['Wamuomata'],['Wan', 'omata'],['Eastboume']
>>> tuple([' '.join(s)] for s in suburbs)
(['Wamuomata'], ['Wan omata'], ['Eastboume'])
```

Note that if you want a single list of strings, as opposed to a tuple of lists of a single string each, it's simpler:

```
>>> [' '.join(s) for s in suburbs]
['Wamuomata', 'Wan omata', 'Eastboume']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the join function inside for loop to join all words in each index

```
new_suburbs = [' '.join(word) for word in suburbs]
```